# Load chrome extension programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

I need to load the chrome extension programatically.It is possible to load using web-driver as well by using external extension preferences.
Is it possible to load it using javascript or any other scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Desiredcapabilities.

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--load-      extension=/path/to/extension/directory"));
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

for detail visit [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

Comment: Yes it is possible by using selenium-webdriver.But currently chromedriver is having a problem in loading the extension.So its not working.So is there any alternative to this?